# Selecting distinct value pairs in EAV

Tags: sql, entity-attribute-value

I'm working on a user database where the profile data has been changed from a simple table into a Entity-Attribute-Value table.

Where as before the structure was along these lines:

```
userid (int)
address 1 (varchar)   
city (varchar)
country (varchar)
```

It's now along these lines:

```
userid (int)
key (varchar)  
value (varchar)
```

eg

```
userid key      value
150    city     London
150    country  UK
151    city     New York
151    country  USA
152    country  Mexico
```

I need to get a distinct list of city / country pairs and a count of all users for each country:

```
city      country  count
London    UK       18
New York  USA      25
```

There is no guarantee each key value pair will exist for each user, i.e there could be city, or country or both or neither as well as any number of other key values pairs.

This was straightforward with the old structure, but I can't even think how to begin on this, and would be grateful for some pointers

Comment: Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I hit myself with this hammer...Then stop hitting yourself with it.

Comment: Quite.  I'd have left it as it was - given the choice...

Comment: Yes, EAV in a _relational_ database is usually a mistake (I believe some NoSQL optionsare geared towards this, with good results).  Besides which, this doesn't address the (perhaps not so obvious) problem of mismatches between city and country.  Or the fact that you don't seem to have a good and quick way to get unique `userId`s (calling `DISTINCT` is not the best option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best solution is to go back to the traditional table because EAV makes most querying much harder than it should be - witness your problems here.  You're going to be doing self-joins until you're sick of them, remanufacturing the table structure that allows you to perform sensible queries.

Cities and countries for each user ID:

```
SELECT a.userID, a.value AS city, b.value AS country
  FROM EAV AS a
  JOIN EAV AS b ON a.UserID = b.UserID
 WHERE a.key = 'city'
   AND b.key = 'country';
```

So, you end up with:

```
SELECT city, country, count(*)
  FROM (SELECT a.userID, a.value AS city, b.value AS country
          FROM EAV AS a
          JOIN EAV AS b ON a.UserID = b.UserID
         WHERE a.key = 'city'
           AND b.key = 'country'
       ) AS c
 GROUP BY city, country;
```

If there's a chance that someone might have two city or two country records, this will give you a Cartesian product with as many rows for that user as the product of the number of city and country records for that user.

This quite deliberately and consciously ignores users who have a city and no country or a country and no city (let alone those who have neither).  Extending the solution to deal with those is only modestly painful - you end up with a 3-way UNION, I think, though you might be able to devise something with multiple left outer joins.  But the fact that data can be entered into an EAV system without the necessary constraints to ensure that there is a city and a country for a user is simply one of the many reasons for rejecting EAV.

I'm sorry you had this foisted on you.  I recommend looking at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ as a way out of your pain, for this is only the beginning of it.

---

Dealing with users without either city or country or both.  I think this will more or less do it:

```
SELECT a.userID, b.value AS city, c.value AS country
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM EAV) AS a
  LEFT JOIN EAV AS b ON a.UserID = b.UserID
  LEFT JOIN EAV AS c ON a.UserID = c.UserID
 WHERE b.key = 'city'
   AND c.key = 'country';
```

This should give you one record per user as long as there are no multiple city or country records for that user.  The `a` scan gives you the list of unique user IDs that exist in the EAV table; the two outer joins give you the corresponding city or cities and corresponding country or countries for each such user ID, with nulls being generated if there is no city record or country record (or both) for the given user ID.

Comment: EAVs are great when you don't know how many keys will be added in the future and/or the number of keys is large.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I completely agree, and seriously dislike this way of doing things, particularly where there is in reality a limited set of attributes to store.  I believe Facebook does it this way and perhaps has a lot to answer for?  I will put your suggestion to work and see if the performance hit is enough to convince my boss to change it back...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It is possible to add `userId` to your second query, without using `MAX`,`MIN` or `ANY_VALUE` function?

Comment: I think you'd simply use `userId` in place of `count(*)` and drop the `GROUP BY` clause, @kicaj.  But that becomes the same as the first query, unless I'm misreading something.  It really depends on what question you're seeking the answer to — when you express that precisely, the query can (probably) be written.

Answer (score 0):

re: *I need to get a distinct list of city / country pairs*

```
SELECT DISTINCT country,city
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT userid, VALUE AS country FROM TABLE WHERE KEY = 'country') country INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT userid, VALUE AS city FROM TABLE WHERE KEY = 'city') city ON
country.userid = city.userid

--count of all users for each country
SELECT VALUE AS country, 
COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS user_count 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE KEY = 'country'
GROUP BY 
VALUE
```